# stock trading in fractions of a penny

Tags: united-states, stocks, shares, real-time-quotes

When I get quote on ITOT or IEMG and some times on IWM, I see quotes in sub penny. [reuters](http://blogs.reuters.com/ben-walsh/2013/11/18/do-stocks-really-trade-for-fractions-of-a-penny-sort-of/) also confirms that it happens, Can a ordinary investor put limit orders in sub-penny ?

I am not asking about penny stocks or thinly traded stocks.

Comment: How many shares are you planning to buy that you think part of one penny per share will actually make a difference?

Comment: @quid , materially it does not matter in sub-penny, but my question is not about does it matter or not, but simply is it allowed for ordinary investor.

Comment: @quid I think for options it makes a big difference, because they are traded in lots of 100

Comment: Yes, it is available for all.

Comment: @MoneyAnn 100 x 25.765 = 2,576.50.  That's 50 cents on $2,500.  That's 0.02%. In most situations the pennies don't make a difference, this person wants to care about parts of pennies.  And IWM is $150/share...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to attract orders and trading volume, ECNs offer maker-taker fees.  In general, if you provide liquidity, they'll provide a sub-penny discount if filled and they charge you the increment for taking liquidity.  A  decent broker will pass 'provided liquidity' this rebate along to you.

I recall reading about one ECN that provides a rebate for takers.  The intent was to encourage investors and brokers who are trading at the market to trade there.  This ECN, if still in existence, is a hotbed for HF traders looking for price discovery.

As for placing orders at sub-penny increments, that would depend your broker's  software.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a ordinary investor put limit orders in sub-penny ?

Only your broker's software knows for sure.